# Is it work making a small bedroom smaller by installing built in booksheves?

Tags: bedroom, remodeling, built-ins

I have a 100 square foot or so bedroom in my townhouse that is my guest room/library/yoga room.  I really want to add built in booksheves around the window, essentially reducing the room size by about 8 1/2 sq ft.  Is this going to be a probolem when selling in 4-5 years or so?  I personally feel it will help by creating more storage and reducing the need for much other furniture in the room but I dont know if I am in the minority or not.  Opinions?  (PS, all of the bedrooms are small, I believe one is around the size this would end up being, so I dont think that the smaller footprint would look out of place)

Comment: Depends on who's buying your house in the future. If I were buying your house, the guest room not having all its potential space wouldn't matter to me. Mostly because its not a crucial room I'd be spending all that much time in. Since you can't predict the future and opinions are just opinions, I wouldl just do it and knock it out later if you feel the need. Chances are before selling you'll be doing some other work too.

Comment: Make sure a standard bed can fit. Don't reduce the wall so much that it can't. Otherwise added shelves don't hurt. If you can also measure a desk or dresser, and design the shelves around space for furniture like that.

Comment: This is a question for a realtor, not a do-it-yourself home improvement site.

Answer (score 3):

Most house buyers won't be going in with a tape measure. If it's likely to be  a problem, your realtor will let you know when its time to sell. They will probably recommend a short list of work to be done anyways (paint is a huge bonus).

In my limited experience as a home-buyer, it wouldn't make a lick of difference. If it looks nice, its a bonus. If it doesn't, I'll plan to tear it off the wall and paint.